# PHP convert long URL (string) in multi line

Tags: php, html

I wanna to show a long string in a cell in a table. But the URL is too long.
How I can convert something like this:

```
/vlive.qqvideo.tc.qq.com/u0020mkrnds.p1203.1.mp4?vkey=7AB139BF6B32F537 47E8FF192E6FE557B3A3D644C034E34BF6EAEB4E0774F2A92EF3AC5C007520BB925E5C 8A18E6D302C2DAE0A295B26AA8FD1DC8069D47CE1B4A16A56870BD1ACA3E86ABE4C079 659DB2182FC71217AB68CCD344CE65694457E3F53549CD617D5C9F671A26C70DC68F93 F1D7BCD017762F&guid=F5EB01CC01A8E08CD83630828DE17C2B02162FD8&locid=a06 f98fd-fa26-44e5-acc5-0d83f9df03af&s ize=9418655&ocid=253564332
```

To

```
/vlive.qqvideo.tc.qq.com/u0020mkrnds.p1203.1.mp4?vkey=7AB139BF6B32F537 
47E8FF192E6FE557B3A3D644C034E34BF6EAEB4E0774F2A92EF3AC5C007520BB925E5C 
8A18E6D302C2DAE0A295B26AA8FD1DC8069D47CE1B4A16A56870BD1ACA3E86ABE4C079 
659DB2182FC71217AB68CCD344CE65694457E3F53549CD617D5C9F671A26C70DC68F93 
F1D7BCD017762F&guid=F5EB01CC01A8E08CD83630828DE17C2B02162FD8&locid=a06
f98fd-fa26-44e5-acc5-0d83f9df03af&size=9418655&ocid=253564332
```

I've read many posts which were about splitting based on words not letters. As you can see, we have one long word/string in the URL.

Any other methods to shorten this URL without delete any information on it will be appreciated.

Comment: How and where are you displaying this? Seems like you could use word-wrap.

Comment: Please share the HTML. Consider reading how to create a [mre]!

Comment: https://www.php.net/wordwrap…?

Comment: `a cell in a table`...you mean a HTML table? What is the constraint - how long is the maximum number of characters? Could you wrap to the next line? (If so, you can simply get the length of the string and use it to calculate a suitable split point(s), and insert a newline (`<br/>` in HTML) at the right place(s).). If not maybe sign up for a URL-shortening service with an API.

Comment: @deceze wordwrap not worked, it works based on words.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php

Comment: @El_Vanja I wanna to show on a cell in a html table. Word-wrap is not useful for this one word.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where ar you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`chunk_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php)

> Can be used to **split** a string into **smaller chunks** which is useful for e.g. converting base64_encode() output to match RFC 2045 semantics. It inserts separator every length characters.

```php
<?php

$data = '/vlive.qqvideo.tc.qq.com/u0020mkrnds.p1203.1.mp4?vkey=7AB139BF6B32F537 47E8FF192E6FE557B3A3D644C034E34BF6EAEB4E0774F2A92EF3AC5C007520BB925E5C 8A18E6D302C2DAE0A295B26AA8FD1DC8069D47CE1B4A16A56870BD1ACA3E86ABE4C079 659DB2182FC71217AB68CCD344CE65694457E3F53549CD617D5C9F671A26C70DC68F93 F1D7BCD017762F&guid=F5EB01CC01A8E08CD83630828DE17C2B02162FD8&locid=a06 f98fd-fa26-44e5-acc5-0d83f9df03af&s ize=9418655&ocid=253564332 ';


echo chunk_split($data, 20, '<br>');
```

The above code would insert a line-break every **20** chars.

Since you're using the data in a htlm table, I would recomend using `<br>` as line-break.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HZFLbhsxEET3OgUXgZQA1ri7STZJ2IpBNslrBJP5RANJ1tj6AMnllYF3tXiFekDN@/nxeH2b9/Nq9a1vr63aqc3z/Tjdh@bj4z71w7m5dktsuvPp@QZAcDp8vveXZkYC3WBzms3b/TD83bmYUIdUOWmqVjtlXPG1YqDCtVjrko46szEC2hRtFrLEkkwB50yluHBVR7EC4CxBSoFssaJ8RF84ayChHAtECjYRx@hrxiweOGTjpGAyETla9g5SxihRF88xlWXQBcU25EToqYpDwsWWvUjWi09hy8EY64pexK0JkhldthIqO4zE4iAL@xq0qphdkgzoHFNd/7lN/a7akgBFAKMv4CV7zRo8@VzQCSUgXNjs18dzt@AtsBqDH/vt2BJvjRnstu06u4Xe6zH0I@h2XF/U9G/YBYOerV1/FWmRY6M1qc3LarUauv1Zdfvb@@HXZT5O1@9fBz4pgie1ef39@XPz4@Xx@A8)

output (See `<br>`s after each **20** chars):

```
/vlive.qqvideo.tc.qq<br>.com/u0020mkrnds.p12<br>03.1.mp4?vkey=7AB139<br>BF6B32F537 47E8FF192<br>E6FE557B3A3D644C034E<br>34BF6EAEB4E0774F2A92<br>EF3AC5C007520BB925E5<br>C 8A18E6D302C2DAE0A2<br>95B26AA8FD1DC8069D47<br>CE1B4A16A56870BD1ACA<br>3E86ABE4C079 659DB21<br>82FC71217AB68CCD344C<br>E65694457E3F53549CD6<br>17D5C9F671A26C70DC68<br>F93 F1D7BCD017762F&g<br>uid=F5EB01CC01A8E08C<br>D83630828DE17C2B0216<br>2FD8&locid=a06 f98fd<br>-fa26-44e5-acc5-0d83<br>f9df03af&s ize=94186<br>55&ocid=253564332 <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to show the whole url in a HTML table, inside a `<td>` and want the url to wrap automatically, you can style with `word-break: break-all;`

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="word-break: break-all;">your url</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I try this. But this didn't worked for me. Thanks